# & not working to separate arugments in a query string

Tags: php, query-string

I have the following code in php to get variables from a query string

```
 $first_name = $_GET['firstName'];
 echo $first_name;
```

when the query string only contains one value like

```
index.php/details?firstName=Austin
```

the value appears on the page like

but for some reason when I try and pass two separate values in the query string like

```
index.php/details?firstName=Austin&lastName=Davis
```

and trying to make the values of the variables appear on the next page like so

```
$first_name = $_GET['firstName'];
$last_name = $_GET['lastName'];
echo $first_name + $last_name;
```

the value zero appears on the webpage. Why can't pass two values in a query string using the & operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is the addition operator in php what you are looking for is `.` which is the concatenation operator. [See more on PHP's Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Change

```
echo $first_name+$last_name;
```

to

```
echo $first_name.$last_name;
```

or better yet

```
echo $first_name.' '.$last_name;
```

By using the addition operator you are basically casting the left and right hand side of the operator to numbers (both of which will result in 0 and the sum of which is 0).

Comment: damn javascript I knew this would happen one day.

Comment: @AustinDavis we all do it time to time :)